# Laravel Signed URL Middlware

Tags: laravel, url, middleware, signed

So I'm working with URL generation with laravel and I was wondering if you can use multiple routes with the same URL Signature.  I have my routes grouped into the signed middlware group as below:

```
Route::middleware('signed')->group(function () {
Route::get('load/client/{client}/quote/{quote}', 'QuoteController@getClientQuote')->name('clientquote');   
Route::post('submit/client/{client}/quote/{quote}', 'QuoteController@submitClientQuote')->name('clientquote');   
Route::post('save/client/{client}/quote/{quote}', 'QuoteController@saveClientQuote')->name('clientquote');   
Route::get('/client/{client}/quote/{quote}', 'QuoteController@getClientQuoteBlade')->name('clientquote');
```

});

I also have the URL generated in an email here:

```
'url'        => URL::signedRoute('clientquote', ['client' => $event->client, 'quote' => $event->quote]),
```

The email is sent through mailgun and when I click on the link in the email it takes me to the last get route in my middlware.  Once that route's component is mounted i make a secondary axios call to get the load route:

```
        axios
        .get(
            "/load/client/" + clientNumber + "/quote/" + quoteNumber + window.location.search
        )
```

leaving off the other code but I get a 403 error and just to verify in the console here is the route:

```
/load/client/2/quote/1?signature=5d2e3273e51429ba688f85969911bd3a279d36348f2e74bd10f871a56218e722
```

is what I'm asking for even possible or do I need to generate a new Signed URL for each subsequent route?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a route under `signed` middleware, it means that all those routes `should` have valid signature. Otherwise it will give you 403 error.

When you call `URL::signedRoute(..)`, that signature particularly represent that specific route url. So if you try to attach the same signature to a different route altogether, it will not work.

What you can do is, when you are sending the data to blade view in `clientquote` route, send the signed url generated as well for `/load/client/` route and then use that in axois.

Comment: that's what I thought unfortunately.  I was hoping there was a way around making multiple signed URLs.  Thanks man.

Comment: So there is no possibility of using the same signature for multiple routes?

Comment: Each signature has hash of metadata specific to the route url you have signed it with. If you want to see whats happening underneath, check `Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` file and `signedRoute` function. You will notice the hash function has specific route details which will be different for other routes